# Full Outer Join in C# with Multiple Conditions

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I am attempting to take 2 datatables, 1 with data from an sql database and 1 with data from an oracle database. The queries themselves work fine, the issue is actually joining them together without losing data. I have tried many different ways suggested in previous stack overflow questions, but they haven't worked either through my lack of understanding (likely) or the code doesn't apply to my situation.

The most recent solution I am working on is this:

```
 var leftOuterJoin = from table1 in mms_dt.AsEnumerable()
                     join table2 in flash_dt.AsEnumerable()
                     on new { X1 = (Decimal)table1["store_number"], X2 = (Decimal)table1["dept"] } equals new { X1 = Convert.ToDecimal(table2["store_number"]), X2 = Convert.ToDecimal(table2["dept"]) }
                     select new
                     {
                         Store = (Decimal)table1["store_number"],
                         Dept = Convert.ToDecimal(table1["dept"]),
                         WinDSS = (Decimal)table1["WinDSS"],
                         CORE = (Decimal)table1["CORE"],
                         RIM = (Decimal)table1["RIM"],
                         POS = (Decimal)table1["WinDSS"] + (Decimal)table1["CORE"],
                         Flash = Convert.ToDecimal(table2["sales_collected"]),
                         Difference = ((Decimal)table1["WinDSS"] + (Decimal)table1["CORE"]) - Convert.ToDecimal(table2["sales_collected"]),
                         Variance = (float)SafeDivision((((Decimal)table1["WinDSS"] + (Decimal)table1["CORE"]) - Convert.ToDecimal(table2["sales_collected"])), Convert.ToDecimal(table2["sales_collected"]))
                     }
                     into selection
                     orderby selection.Store, selection.Dept
                     select selection;

var rightOuterJoin = from table2 in flash_dt.AsEnumerable()
                     join table1 in mms_dt.AsEnumerable()
                     on new { X1 = Convert.ToDecimal(table2["store_number"]), X2 = Convert.ToDecimal(table2["dept"]) } equals new { X1 = Convert.ToDecimal(table1["store_number"]), X2 = Convert.ToDecimal(table1["dept"]) }
                     select new
                     {
                         Store = Convert.ToDecimal(table2["store_number"]),
                         Dept = Convert.ToDecimal(table2["dept"]),
                         WinDSS = (Decimal)table1["WinDSS"],
                         CORE = (Decimal)table1["CORE"],
                         RIM = (Decimal)table1["RIM"],
                         POS = (Decimal)table1["WinDSS"] + (Decimal)table1["CORE"],
                         Flash = Convert.ToDecimal(table2["sales_collected"]),
                         Difference = ((Decimal)table1["WinDSS"] + (Decimal)table1["CORE"]) - Convert.ToDecimal(table2["sales_collected"]),
                         Variance = (float)SafeDivision((((Decimal)table1["WinDSS"] + (Decimal)table1["CORE"]) - Convert.ToDecimal(table2["sales_collected"])), Convert.ToDecimal(table2["sales_collected"]))
                     }
                     into selection
                     orderby selection.Store, selection.Dept
                     select selection;

var res = leftOuterJoin.Union(rightOuterJoin);

foreach (var item in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

mms_dt and flash_dt are my 2 tables of data. I want to perform the join on every row which has store number and department matching. Both tables contain "store_number" and "dept". mms_dt also contains the columns "WinDSS, CORE, RIM" while flash_dt contains "sales_collected" instead. When this code is run, it only shows rows that have data from both tables, missing the entire point of a full outer join. I'm 99% sure I'm making a dumb mistake in the syntax, due to my lack of SQL knowledge.